# Flow layout behavior using plain old HTML?

Tags: html, dom, layout

Using plain old HTML, how can I achieve a layout like this?

[image]

I've got 10-50 dynamic elements in an array, and I need to display them as shown.

If I just add all them to a container div, it goes left to right.

If each element is a div, they stack top to bottom, but never wrap to the next column.

How is this typically achieved using plain old HTML? **edit** I need this to work dynamically, e.g. if there maybe only be 2 items, or 50; I can't hard-code 3 <ul> lists.

Comment: What do you mean by "plain old HTML"? You don't want to use CSS?

Comment: I meant, I don't want to resort to javascript hackery to achieve the flow layout. I was hoping there was a HTML/CSS way to make this work without having to write custom behavior with JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
.flow ul {
    float: left;
}

.flow li {
    list-style: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="flow">
        <ul>
            <li>Albany, 1324</li>
            <li>Albuquerque, 3456</li>
            <li>Baton Rouge, 4566</li>
            <li>Bellvue, 9856</li>
            <li>Catameran, 75696</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>D SiteName, 1324</li>
            <li>E SiteName, 3456</li>
            <li>F SiteName, 4566</li>
            <li>SiteName, 9856</li>
            <li>SiteName, 75696</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>SiteName, 1324</li>
            <li>SiteName, 3456</li>
            <li>SiteName, 4566</li>
            <li>SiteName, 9856</li>
            <li>SiteName, 75696</li>
       </ul>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Or if you mean something without CSS when you say, "plain old HTML", you might want something like this but this is perhaps not something you want because it doesn't use the `<div>` element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Test</title>
<body>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <ul>
            <li>Albany, 1324</li>
            <li>Albuquerque, 3456</li>
            <li>Baton Rouge, 4566</li>
            <li>Bellvue, 9856</li>
            <li>Catameran, 75696</li>
        </ul>
    </td>
    <td>
        <ul>
            <li>D SiteName, 1324</li>
            <li>E SiteName, 3456</li>
            <li>F SiteName, 4566</li>
            <li>SiteName, 9856</li>
            <li>SiteName, 75696</li>
        </ul>
    </td>
    <td>
        <ul>
            <li>SiteName, 1324</li>
            <li>SiteName, 3456</li>
            <li>SiteName, 4566</li>
            <li>SiteName, 9856</li>
            <li>SiteName, 75696</li>
       </ul>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

You might also want to use lines terminated with `<br>` elements intead of `<ul>` and `<li>` elements depending on what you need.

Comment: BTW, I am using shiny new HTML5 here. You can change the DOCTYPE to use some plain old HTML4.01 Strict perhaps. :-)

Comment: Hm. Well, my items list is dynamic, retrieved from an AJAX call. So I don't think this works exactly, but it gives me an idea how to do this with a bit of template hackery. Thanks.

Comment: Of course you have to think and develop the logic to display the elements in your array in three separate lists. We can do that for you here because we don't know exactly what you are doing. :-) But I hope one of the two examples I have posted above will help you get started. :-)

Comment: this solution is correct to an extent because with current html / css, its the only way to make things naturally float. If you have variable lengths of json data coming in, you'll need to get jsonObject.length/3, and then do a for loop with that number (dont forget about your remainders using the % operator), then those three lists will float left into three side-by-side columns.

Comment: You're right - I can use these answers to get me off the ground, working out the dynamic data from there. Thank you.

Comment: Since, it appears to me that you are new to CSS `float`, let me tell you that you might run into some surprising issues if you are planning to put this list inside some other `div` container with borders, background, etc.

If that happens, to learn how to fix it just search for "float containment" in the web or go through my note on this: http://notes.susam.in/2011/06/float-containment.html

If your web page is going to be simple without these things, then you'll probably not face any issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use tables. God only knows people use them far more than they should for graphics, but this is what they were built for.

I don't know that you can get it to automatically wrap, but even if you use floats- you'll still have to predefine columns anyway.

You can find syntax [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp).

Answer (score 1):

In plain old HTML, you would use `ordered lists` and reset the lists for each column.

```
<ol>
    <li>.</li>
    <li>.</li>
    <li>.</li>
    <li>.</li>
</ol>

<ol start="5">
    <li>.</li>
    <li>.</li>
    <li>.</li>
    <li>.</li>
</ol>
```

Etc.

Then `float` the lists to the left.

Of course, this would not dynamically update.

**EDIT**

As per comment, you can do this dynamically with CSS3

```
div{
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 1em;
    column-rule: 1px solid black;
    -moz-column-count: 3; 
    -moz-column-gap: 1em; 
    -moz-column-rule: 1px solid black; 
    -webkit-column-count: 3; 
    -webkit-column-gap: 1em; 
    -webkit-column-rule: 1px solid black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/3GSp6/1/

This is modern browsers only. Chrome, Firefox, Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Like this : http://jsfiddle.net/PTLm6/5/